# OS X Lion Mail.app sound effects bug

Tags: macos, mail.app

This is one of the weirdest bug that I've observed:
It seems that Mail.app's audio notifications for new mail and sending mail accumulate and play in order of occurrence when I unplug external speakers. Just now it played a series of more than 100 notifications (mostly new mail notification).

It's not big enough that I want to fix it but I just wanted to know if anyone experienced something similar.

It happened on an iMac that was upgraded to OS X Lion from Snow Leopard.

Comment: So you had external speakers connected, playing fine non muted, and then upon unplugging the external speakers backlogged alert sounds play via the internal speakers, is that about what is happening?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't happen regularly and I don't know how to reproduce it.

Comment: Yes Just experienced  this on a Mac Mini as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this bug is repeatable and happens often you should consider filing a bug with Apple via their, [Apple Bug Reporter](https://bugreport.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/RadarWeb.woa/wa/signIn).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer, but here is how to reproduce the error. Open mail.app then call someone on FaceTime.

Comment: Try to avoid answers like "I have this issue too". Provide a solution or some work-around to actually solve the original question.

Comment: In general @Michiel is correct but given the accepted answer, this adds great actionable information to others and might get us to a real fix other than "it's a bug - file a bug report" which is also something to avoid in general, but here works fine.